# Mapping doesn't work for tabs

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, tabbed-user-interface

I have several files opened in tabs in Vim.
I want to switch between tabs, so I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to move left (previous) and for next also.
But my mapping doesn't work.

```
:map <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
:map <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
```

I tried in <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> combinations. It doesn't work in command line as well as vimrc also.

Comment: Why not `gt` and `gT`?

Comment: Thanks. It works. :) Can you tell me what causes my mapping not to work?

Comment: @SibiCoder Maybe because Vim didn't set up the modified arrow keys. In your `vimrc`, you could try adding this line `exe "set <xRight>=\e[1;*C" | exe "set <xLeft>=\e[1;*D"`. If this doesn't work, could you post what is displayed in a Vim buffer when you insert a literal `<C-Left>` (`<C-V>` then `<C-Left>` in insert mode)? Or maybe `<C-Left>` is already bound to some function in your terminal emulator, so Vim never receives this keystroke.

Comment: I can say that it works for me. Maybe (just maybe) you've remapped arrows or something. You can try show us your vimrc.

Comment: I started with vim -u NONE . and mapped in command line, it doesn't work

Comment: Try with `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: Receiving E388: Couldn't find definition.    It doesn't work. My versions is 7.2

Comment: Do I need to delete the question since it appears to be a issue/bug related one? Are issue related questions allowed here?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24974438) explains why this is impossible:

> Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this
>   unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key
>   combinations, like **Ctrl + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped**, and Ctrl +
>   letter vs. Ctrl + Shift + letter cannot be distinguished.

Comment: The post you quote is totally outdated. Currently `<C-Left>` and `<C-Right>` do work in gVim, and, depending on terminal, in plain Vim too.

Comment: @Matt not for me they don't, but that's because macOS intercepts them to change workspaces